# field value contained in list

Tags: webservices, class, apex

I have an apex class where I need to check if a field value of a particular record is contained in a pre-defined list. Please find my code here.Can someone please help?
Apex class:

```
global class Account_chk {
  WebService static void method1(Id i) {
  List<Call2_vod__c> a= new List<Call2_vod__c>();
  List<Attachment> p=new List<Attachment> ();
    List<Attachment> exist=new List<Attachment> ();
    exist=[select ParentId,id from Attachment];
    a=[select Name,Id,Signature_vod__c,Signature_Date_vod__c,Account_vod__c from Call2_vod__c where Signature_Date_vod__c !=Null limit 100];
    for (Call2_vod__c call:a)
    {          
        Attachment record = new Attachment(Name = Call.Id ,ParentId = call.Account_vod__c , Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(call.Signature_vod__c), ContentType = 'image/jpeg');
        if(exist.contains(record.parentId))
         p.add(record);          
    }
    try { insert(p);
    } 
    catch(System.DMLException e){
      System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Issue is with below line :

```
if(exist.contains(record.parentId))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build up a map of Attachments using ParentId as the key, like so:

```
exist=[select ParentId,id from Attachment];

Map<Id, Attachment> existMap = new Map<Id, Attachment>();

for (Attachment att : exist) {

    existMap.put(att.ParentId, att);

}
```

and then check the map contents:

```
if (existMap.get(record.ParentId).Id != null) {

}
```

Comment: Hi DavinC! It is working! Thanks but I facing a Null pointer exception and Limit Exception here for evaluating records more than 200 or so.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I would suggest posting a new question about the errors you're now seeing, as opposed to hyjacking this one.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing if a `List of Attachment` contains an `Id`. It's not correct !

Try :

```
if(exist.contains(record))
```

Comment: Thanks SF_User! just a question. ParentId field should be matched with exist and record , name or other fields may differ.Should it take care of such cases?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want !

Comment: I mean I need to match ParentId of record(yet to be created) with ParentId of exist. Can this operation be done by this?